# How to compile typescript to use CommonJS and import/export?

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, commonjs, tsconfig

For example, I have an index.ts file in which a function that returns the sum of two numbers is exported via export. And also the test.js file which imports the function from the already compiled index.js file,how can I make it so that I can import the function through require and also import?

Example in index.ts:

```js
export default (a: number, b: number): number => a + b;
```

And I need to be able to do this in test.js:

```js
import num from "./index.js";
// OR
const num = require("./index.js");
```

How can I do this, maybe through a configuration file or a library, a framework, a piece of code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve compatibility for both CommonJS (Node.js require) and ES6 module syntax (import), you can do the following:

Use TypeScript tsconfig.json:
In your tsconfig.json file, set the "module" option to "commonjs".

{
"compilerOptions": {
"module": "commonjs",
// other options...
}
}

Use module.exports in TypeScript:
In your index.ts file, use module.exports along with the default export

const sum = (a: number, b: number): number => a + b;

export default sum;
module.exports = sum;

// Using ES6 import
import num from "./index";

// Using CommonJS require
const num = require("./index");

This way, your TypeScript code is compatible with both ES6 modules and CommonJS, allowing you to use import and require interchangeably.

Comment: `import num from "./index.js"; `
       ^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module './index.js' does not provide an export named 'default'